# Is it possible to install SQL Server Express edition side by side with SQL Server Developer edition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2016-express

I have looked at Microsoft Documentation but didn't find an answer, I already have SQL Server 2016 Express edition on my machine and wonder if it's possible to install SQL Server 2016 Developer edition side by side with the Express edition?

Comment: Not sure about 2016 version specifically, but in general, yes you can. My machine used to have SQL 2008R2 Dev and SQL2014 Express. You will need to install Dev edition as a named instance though.

Comment: Yes, you can have as many separate **instances** of SQL Server of different versions and editions side-by-side as you like - you just have to give each instance a **unique name**. Typically, a SQL Server **Express** is installed as the `SQLEXPRESS` instance - so you need to name your Developer edition differently

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, my machine has SQL Server 2008R2 Express, SQL Server 2012 Express, and SQL Server 2016 Developer Edition